# Is there a general correlation between the number of homophones in a language and how phonetic its writing system is?

Tags: phonology, written-language

When I think of languages that have a high number of homophones, I think of Japanese, Mandarin, English and French.

And when I think of languages with relatively opaque writing systems that are not particularly phonetic, I think of Japanese, Mandarin, English and French.

Conversely, Spanish, Italian, Portuguese, Indonesian and Modern Greek have relatively few homophones and highly phonetic writing systems.

Is this explained purely by coincidence, or is there something more to this?

I can only speak for the languages already mentioned, but is there a similar trend across other languages of the world?

Comment: I am not familiar with Japanese but aren't 3 out of its 4 writing styles *highly* phonetic? (Kanji being the exception. The 4th writing style being Romanji)

Comment: Yes, the two kana scripts are very phonetic, but they are used for words that don't already have a kanji representation, grammatical additions to kanji or for foreign words. 

And Romanji, or Latin script, is used only certain simple things like AM/PM, BC/AD.

Comment: It's Romaji, by the way.

Comment: Actually there are various classes of words that have kanji spellings but are generally written in kana these days. Names of some foreign countries and names of some animals I think are two such classes. There are also words which are commonly written in either kanji or kana, sometimes even commonly in both katakana and hiragana as well as kanji. Nothing is ever simple in Japanese! (-:

Comment: There are different kinds of "opaque" writing systems. English is opaque for everyone but very good spellers. French is opaque to English speakers but crystal clear to French speakers. I'm pretty sure the same could be said of Mandarian and Japanese. It's opaque to you and me because we haven't learned them. Then again I know some of my Japanese friends are terrible spellers in Japanese - get some kanji mixed up - I'm assuming the ones which overlap to agree both  visually and phonetically, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: What is a homophone in your definition? Words with similar pronunciations that have the SAME spelling (homonym)? Or different (heterograph)? or doesn't matter? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone]
Indic languages have no difference in pronunciation and writing : thus no possibility of heterographs. Homonyms are rare. In support of your hypothesis.

Comment: I meant homophone in a purely auditory sense, i.e. words that sound the same, regardless of how they're spelt. 

Using your terminology, which is how I should have formulated the idea originally, I would suppose that a language with a relatively higher degree of homophoneity would have a relatively higher degree of heteronymeity, which would make the writing system more opaque and less phonetic.

Answer (score 5):

Korean arguably fits the bill as a language with both a high amount of homophones and a highly phonetic writing system.

I will start with the writing system since it is the most cut and dry. [Hangul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) is by far the most common writing system in Korean. Spelling adheres closely to pronunciation with a few exceptions. It should be noted, however, that those exceptions are all regular. That is, knowing a small handful of pronunciation rules you can reliably produce a faithful pronunciation of a word from written form alone. Some of these rules include nasal assimilation of approximates when preceded by a nasal (as in 종로, literally *jong-ro*, a district in Seoul, but actually pronounced as *jong-no*), and neutralization of codas (받, 밭, 밧, and 밪, literally *bat*, *bath*, *bas*, and *bac* respectively, are all pronounced as *bat* due to neutralization).

Hangul is kept highly phonetic by occasional revisions to Korean spelling to match modern pronunciation (*note*: I was unable to find an appropriate citation for this. This is what my sociolinguistics professor told me.). I believe the last such update was in the 1950s.

North Korea uses Hangul exclusively however South Korea does have a second writing system, [Hanja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanja), which is basically Traditional Chinese characters (with some variation, but less than Kanji or Simplified Chinese). This system predates Hangul as before Hangul's invention Koreans wrote using Chinese characters. It should be noted that these days Hanja is almost exclusively used in TV news and newspapers (mostly for disambiguation), as well as for artistic purposes (store signs, calligraphy, etc.).

The relatively recent invention of Hangul combined with the existence and use of the Hanja writing system is what makes the statement "Korean uses a highly phonetic writing system" debatable. However from my experience living in Korea and learning the language I would argue that since Hanja is used only in limited context (you will never see a sentence written entirely in Hanja, if only because all Hanja-based verbs and adjectives must end in 하다, *ha-ta*, dictionary form of "to do", which is pure Korean), it does have a highly phonetic writing system.

Second, the statement that Korean has a [high level of homophone](http://www.lexiophiles.com/english/korean-homophones) (*note*: forgive the non-academic source). It should be noted that this statement too is [up for debate](http://seedyroad.com/academics/JournalOfLinguistics-46-453-482.pdf) as, amongst other reasons, homophone usually does not create ambiguity when viewed in context. Much of Korean vocabulary, especially written and formal vocabulary, is adopted from Chinese (much like English uses French/Latin vocabulary). Given the relatively small sets of phonemes in Chinese and the fact that Korean is not tonal and thus can't differentiate through tones, this leaves many sets of words with identical spellings and thus pronunciations.

Common examples include lexical items like:

> **매매** - *mae-mae* - 賣買 - literally "buying and selling"
>   **수상** - *swu-sang* - 1) 受賞 - winning a prize, 2) 授賞 - awarding a prize (somewhat archaic)
>   **기타** - *ki-tha* - 1) guitar (English loanword), 2) 其他 - other, the rest

And my personal favourite,

> **시간** - *si-kan* - 1) 時間 - an hour, time, 2) 屍姦 - necrophilia (definitely **not** in common usage)

As well as full sentences such as:

> 아이가 방에 있어
>   ai-ka bang-ey iss-a
>   child-SUB room-LOC exist-INFORMAL
>   The child is in [his] room.

> 아이 가방에 있어
>   ai kabang-ey iss-a
>   child bag-LOC exist-INFORMAL
>   The child is in the bag.

Technically these two differ by the voicing on "ka" (voiced in the first, unvoiced in the second) but Korean does not differentiate consonants based on voicing and spoken at a conversational speed they sound identical.

Comment: Nice, thorough answer -- I thought Korean might be an exception. Do you have any sense of how difficult it is to follow a written sentence because of the homophones? Is it a complete non-issue, or would it, in your subjective feel for the language, make reading easier to have some more prevalent disambiguation in the written language?

Comment: Personally, my vocabulary is small so when I look up a word in a dictionary and it has 5 completely different definitions then I find it very challenging. I cannot speak for native Korean speakers but I don't think it's big a problem for them. Newspapers like Chosun and Korea Times (Korean Edition) don't use any Hanja, with no added confusion. With examples like 매매, instead of the Chinese, they tend to use the pure Korean 팔다 (*par-ta* - to sell) and 사다 (*sa-ta* - to buy). In the other cases, competing definitions are ruled out because they are uncommon or by semantics. Context is king.

Comment: `before Hangul's invention Koreans wrote using Chinese characters`: Actually hangul was invented in the 15th century but wasn't even used in official documents until ~400 years later. Possibly the place you'll most notice Hanja in South Korea today is train and metro stations where all station names are written in two or three scripts. I'm not sure whether this is to have a traditional flavour or to help Chinese and Japanese expats and visitors.

Comment: @hippietrail yes, I was oversimplifying. Hangul was also outlawed by the Japanese from their annex of Korea in 1910 until Korea's independence in 1945. As for Hanja in the metro system, that's more for the benefit of Chinese and Japanese tourists. On Line 2 (Seoul's major circle line) announcements for major stations are made in Korean, English, Mandarin, and Japanese.

Comment: I should be there this time next week. I'll keep my eye open (-;